Salesforce code analyzer returns issue when using "as user" with dml
When I use delete with 'as user' and run sf code analyzer i get this problem:
"PMDException: Error while parsing E:\testpro\force-app\main\default\classes\TestCl.cls
Caused by: net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.ast.ParseException: apex.jorje.services.exception.ParseException: Syntax(error = UnexpectedToken(loc = (71, 20, 435, 437), token = 'as'))","","Scanner Internal","pmd"

What is the problem? How to fix it?

This is a problem with the PMD parser. I've notified someone who's involved with ApexPMD regarding the problem. For now, you'll have to ignore it or change the source code to not use it. That said, this is also a relatively new Apex language feature, so please make sure you're running the latest version of ApexPMD.
